# How do I only print statement once in a while loop?

Tags: java, while-loop

```
  {
  System.out.println("Enter input file name:");
  Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
  String fileName = keyboard.nextLine();
  File read = new File(fileName);
  Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(read);

  if(read.length() == 0)
  {
     System.out.println("empty file");
     return;
  }

  inputFile.useDelimiter(":");
  String name, code, line, distance;
  System.out.println("Enter station name");
  String stationName = keyboard.nextLine();


  while(inputFile.hasNextLine())
  {
    name = inputFile.next();
    code = inputFile.next();
    line = inputFile.next();
    distance = inputFile.nextLine();

     if(stationName.equalsIgnoreCase(name))
     {
        System.out.println("Station code: " + code + " name: " + name);
        System.out.println("distance " + distance + " kms, is on the " + line + " line");
     }

     else if(!stationName.equalsIgnoreCase(name))
     {
        System.out.println("No information was found for station " + stationName);
     }
```

As you can see the final line of code will be printed out multiple times for however many lines of code there are in the text file. Is there any way to make this only print once?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could declare a boolean variable hasPrinted = false, then make then add && !hasPrinted to your else if statement, and in the logic inside set the hasPrinted to true

Comment: Write a wrapper method for System.out.println that returns true.Call it say "print". Break after print method.

Comment: Note: you don't need an else if condition in this example. else is enough, because you only enter the second block, if stationName isn't equal to name

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess what you want to do is to display this error message only once you have read the entire file. You could use a boolean variable `stationFound` initialized to `false` and that you set to `true` when you found a matching station.
*After* your while loop, you can then check if `stationFound` is true, and if not display your error message.

Note that you can also use a `break` once you have found a matching station to avoid reading the whole file when not needed.

Here is what it would look like in code:

```
boolean stationFound = false;
while(inputFile.hasNextLine())
{
    // ...
    if(stationName.equalsIgnoreCase(name))
    {
        System.out.println("Station code: " + code + " name: " + name);
        System.out.println("distance " + distance + " kms, is on the " + line + " line");
        stationFound = true;
        break;
     }
}


if(!stationFound)
{
    System.out.println("No information was found for station " + stationName);
}
```

Comment: Only answer that actually seems to understand what he is trying to do

Answer (score -2):

If you want to print this statement once and exits the loop
you can add
break; after the if statement

```
else if(!stationName.equalsIgnoreCase(name))
     {
        System.out.println("No information was found for station " + stationName);
break;
     }
```

Answer (score -2):

Have you considered inserting a break?

```
 else if(!stationName.equalsIgnoreCase(name))
{
    System.out.println("No information was found for station " + stationName);
    break;
}
```